# how to get value "font-size:xxx" from input type=text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```html
<style type="text/css">input[type="text"]{font-size:38px;width:700px;}</style>

 <p id="info"></p>

 <input type="text" name="tld" onkeyup="document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
 this.value.length
 + '<hr />'
 + this.style.width
 + '<hr />'
 + this.style.fontSize;" />
```

but this only show value of length, I need width (of box) and size (of font).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get the information you are looking for.

```html
<style type="text/css">input[type="text"]{font-size:38px;width:700px;}</style>

 <p id="info"></p>

 <input type="text" name="tld" onkeyup="document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
 this.value.length
 + '<hr />'
 + window.getComputedStyle(this).width
 + '<hr />'
 + window.getComputedStyle(this).fontSize;" />
```